# Does Ubuntu Studio come with Ardour installed?

Tags: ardour

Does Ubuntu Studio come with Ardour install?
Does it come with lifetime updates?

Sorry for the dumb question, I lack the skills to code or take a source code and make it into an app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Ardour is pre-installed with Ubuntustudio. On the official [Ubuntustudio website](https://ubuntustudio.org/tour/audio/), Ardour is mentioned in the audio tour. However, you don't need to compile from source to install an app on Ubuntu.

You can easily install Ardour by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ardour
```

You can also install Ardour by using the Ubuntu Software Center app which comes pre-installed in all Ubuntu flavours.

Finally, Ubuntustudio does not come with lifetime updates. You will need to switch to a newer version of Ubuntu every few years. Currently, you can run Ubuntustudio 18.04 until April of 2021.

After you install 18.04, you will need to run the following commands to [ensure extended support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/BackportsPPA):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntustudio-ppa/backports 
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

The `sudo apt update` command checks for any updates and the `sudo apt full-upgrade` command actually performs the software updates. It is good habit to run these two commands often to keep your system up to date.

Then, in April of 2020 or later, you can run the following commands to switch to Ubuntustudio version 20.04 LTS (this will take some time so make sure to plug in your computer and don't turn your computer off):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntustudio-ppa/backports 
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Additionally, you can always check with the [official website](https://ubuntustudio.org) for any news.

Comment: You can also search for software by running the following command like in this example: `apt-cache search ardour` or `apt-cache search audio` or you can use the software center to search for applications to install.